# Getting a $value into a .php page form table for a calculator

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, html-table

Sorry if this is really basic programming knowledge, but if it is should only take a moment to help me.  I've tried lots of things and searches already but can't get it to work.

I'm doing a tutorial from http://www.hungrypiranha.org/make-a-website/online-calculator

I'm making a settings page that will edit a config.php file with a simple price in it.  I have set it to 5. I will work out some way to make that editable later with a user interface.  One step at a time.

```
    <?php
//config file
$price = "5";
?>
```

Next I put the calculator script into the index.php page,
but I want to draw out the `$price` value from the other file and put it into the form table.  No matter what I try it doesn't go into the form table.
It goes anywhere I put the code `<?php echo $price; ?>`, but not into the form table.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Net Calc</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=300">
 </head>
 <body>

<div>
<?php include("config.php"); ?>
<?php echo '<p>Netting Price Calculator</p>'; ?>
<p>Current price per m2 is $<label><?=$price?></label></br>
<a href="settings.php">link to Settings</a>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['valuea'])) $valuea = $_POST['valuea'];
if (isset($_POST['valueb'])) $valueb = $_POST['valueb'];
$answer = $valuea * $valueb * $price;

echo <<<_END
<form method='post' action=''>
<table border='0' width='300px' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' class="table">
<tr class="calcheading"><td colspan="2"><strong>Netting Price Calculator</strong></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow"><td>Height</td><td align="left"><input type='text' name='valuea' value="$valuea"/></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow2"><td>Width:</td><td align="left"><input type='text' name='valueb' value="$valueb"/></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow"><td>Price:</td><td align="left"><?php echo $price; ?></td></tr>
<tr class="submit"><td colspan="2"><input type='submit' value='Calculate'/><input type='reset' value='Reset'/></td></tr>
_END;
?>

<tr class="calcrow">
<td><i>Total:</td>
<td align="left">$<?php echo $answer; ?></td></i>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</br><?=$price?>
</br><?php echo $price; ?>
</br>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

What I put into the `$price` variable doesn't want to show on the page.
Hope you understand.  If you get what I'm asking and know of any better calculator tutorials please let me know.

Comment: Thanks no luck.  That works fine at the top or bottom of the page but not inside the table call.

Comment: Error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php should be throwing you a whole bunch of notices.

Comment: Now; the problem here, is that you're inside heredoc and this `<?php echo $price; ?>` is literally printing that, if you view your HTML source, you'll see for yourself `<td align="left"><?php echo $price; ?></td>`. Just remove the `<?php echo ; ?>` and keep `$price` from inside the form. The rest, you'll need to take care of yourself. Your answer is this (in a nutshell).

Comment: Let me know if you want that ^ as the answer to be posted. Otherwise, you can see the answer that was posted below. They took out your heredoc; if that's what you want. I explained what was going on here. Edit: I have to go to bed.

Comment: Hi Fred,  Your solution worked.  I didn't expect to just put $price there, but thank you thats great.  I will look at the solution below now.  Have a nice sleep.

Comment: Glad to hear it Kurt. Yeah,.. I really had to get some shut-eye. And you're welcome. Glad to have been of help,  *cheers*

Answer (score 1):

It's better for everyone to write more readable code.
Also I suggest you to write html outsite php tag. So you will see easier debug.

Your problem is happen around `echo <<<_END`. So, I suggest you to do like this.

```
 <?php
       if (isset($_POST['valuea'])) $valuea = $_POST['valuea'];
       if (isset($_POST['valueb'])) $valueb = $_POST['valueb'];
       $answer = $valuea * $valueb * $price;

       //your form was here but I move it outside of the php tag.

 ?>

 <form method='post' action=''>
      <table border='0' width='300px' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' class="table">
          <tr class="calcheading">
               <td colspan="2">
                     <strong>Netting Price Calculator</strong>
               </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="calcrow">
               <td>Height</td>
               <td align="left">
                    <input type='text' name='valuea' value="<?php echo $valuea?>"/>
              </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="calcrow2">
              <td>Width:</td>
              <td align="left">
              <input type='text' name='valueb' value="<?php $valueb?>"/>
              </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="calcrow">
              <td>Price:</td>
              <td align="left"><?php echo $price; ?></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="submit">
              <td colspan="2"><input type='submit' value='Calculate'/>
                     <input type='reset' value='Reset'/>
              </td>
         </tr>
```

I also update your input value from `value="$valuea"` to `<?php echo $valuea?>`

because I write it outside php tag. so when you want to display php variable just do `<?php` and `?>` inside html.

I test this your varible inside table form work fine.

> little thing

I suggest to put `include` at first line of file.

`<?php include("config.php"); ?>`

And if you really need and the script will not work without it. you better use require.

`<?php require_once("config.php"); ?>`

Comment: Your answer will still throw undefined variable notices.

Comment: @Fred-ii- There are some variable need to post into. I was checked that already. It's work with post data.

Comment: @KurtLane you're welcome. Don't forget to check correct anwser. Better for everryone to know this problem was solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I pointed out in comments; the problem here is that you're inside [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)
and this `<?php echo $price; ?>` is literally printing that.

If you look(ed) at your HTML source, you would have seen
`<td align="left"><?php echo $price; ?></td>` rather than the parsed variable assigned.

Simply remove the `<?php echo ; ?>` and keep `$price` from inside the form.

However, you will receive undefined variable(s) notices for all the variables you have declared.

You will need to first check if they are set, and/or not empty.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Or using a ternary operator: (See under **Ternary Operator**)

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Example pulled from the manual on the ternary operator:

```
$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];
```

This can be adapted to variables also and replacing `empty` by `isset`.

Error reporting would have signaled that:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

---

**HTML stickler:**

`</br>` isn't a valid HTML markup tag; `<br/>` and `<br>` are.